# javascript parseInt to change an image depending on an input text

Tags: javascript, html, image, case, parseint

I have the following function that changes an  named imager, depending on the number typed on the input text named textvalue. But this does not work. I am not sure if I have used parseInt correctly.

function conditioner (){

```
    var textvaluevariable= parseInt(document.getElementById("textvalue").innerHTML,10);
    switch (textvaluevariable) {
    case 0:
        document.getElementById("imager").src = "b1.png";
        break;
    case 1:
        document.getElementById("imager").src = "g1.png";
        break;
    case 2:
        document.getElementById("imager").src = "b1.png";
        break;
    case 3:
        document.getElementById("imager").src = "g1.png";
        break;
    case 4:
        document.getElementById("imager").src = "b1.png";
        break;
    case 5:
        document.getElementById("imager").src = "g1.png";
        break;
    case 6:
        document.getElementById("imager").src = "b1.png";
        break;
}


}
```

Comment: Are you really only using those two images? Because in that case: `imagerElement.src = (parseInt(textvaluevariable,10) % 2 === 0 ? 'g' : 'b') + '1.png'; would seem to work.

Comment: yes there is no problem with images. I tried switch alert(textvaluevariable); and it showed NaN. The following answer worked well. (answer by Darek)

Comment: Your comment doesn't really clarify anything (or I really haven't slept enough); providing a live demo might be of use, though apparently your question has been answered by Derek..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `innerHTML` to `value`:

```
var textvaluevariable= parseInt(document.getElementById("textvalue").value ,10);
```

Reference: [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)